# Added repository to Nexus but still not finding artifacts

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I have a project that uses the hl7api (HAPI) available at http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/m2

In my pom I have defined a repository with this url. If I don't go via local nexus it works but when I do it will not find the artifacts. I have added a proxy repository in Nexus with the same url.

Any ideas?

Comment: what url are you using when you swap to nexus? are you using are group? if yes, then have you added the proxied repository to the group?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public is the url in my settings.xml (in .m2 folder). yeah i've added the repository in from the available repositories in the public group. still can't see it

Comment: Can you index that particular repository?

Comment: there is no index available as far as i know. in the repository configuration i added the same url as a mirror and it seemed to start working!

Comment: I've done all steps but still doesn't work for me. Is there something other that i need to do?

Comment: right click the proxy repository ,and choose "Update Index",also try acess it form this url: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21433982-Debugging-why-Nexus-cannot-find-an-artifact-describe-      like :http://locahost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/com/microsoft/ews-java-api/ews-java-api/2.0-SNAPSHOT/ews-java-api-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?describe      ,if met this " cached until 2015-08-14T21:44:22.174-07:00 as not found in repository M2Repository(id=central) " then right click the repository ,choose "Expire Cache" ,go back to "Rooting' tab for in this repository ,if the file is in browse Index .

Answer (score 4):

If you added the repository as a `proxy repository` in Nexus do not forget to add the proxy to the [Repository Group](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-adding-to-group.html#fig-add-to-group) which you use as [mirror](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) for all Nexus requests (public/snapshot) - assumed you have this kind of configuration.

Sorry - just saw that this solution was discussed as comment on the question. Can not delete the answer but it seems to be obsolete.