# Nexus proxy repository

Tags: proxy, nexus

I'm new to Nexus. I have added a proxy repository for http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/repo/. Its added successfully. I can browse the repository content in the 'Browse remote' tab. But when I point my maven to my local Nexus mirror & execute it fails while accessing dependency for reflections, its not able to locate it in my nexus repository.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you added the repository as a `proxy repository` in Nexus do not forget to add the proxy to the [Repository Group](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-adding-to-group.html#fig-add-to-group) which you use as [mirror](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) for all Nexus requests (public/snapshot) - assumed you have this kind of configuration.

(Took this from a former [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031624/added-repository-to-nexus-but-still-not-finding-artifacts/5160023#5160023) from me.)

Comment: Struggled for hours! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to access the proxy directly?
I think it is better to create a group repository and add the Google repository there.