# Add mysql connector to a maven / nexus build in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, nexus

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database in java and so I have to add  `mysql-connector-java:jar` to my eclipse project. The integration with maven is not working though.

Here is what I have in my settings.xml:

```
<profile>
<id>default</id>
<properties>
 <mvn.path>.../maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn.bat</mvn.path>
 <javac.5>...bin/javac.exe</javac.5> 
 <javac.6>..../javac.exe</javac.6>
</properties>
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>central-repository</id>
  <name>OSS central Maven Release Repository</name>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>public-repository-main</id>
  <name>Central Repository</name>
  <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>public-repository</id>
  <name>OSS Maven Release Repository</name>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
</profile>

<interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode> 
<!-- offline
 | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing
 | a build.
 | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
 |
 | Default: false <offline>false</offline> -->
<offline>false</offline>
<mirror> 
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://xxxx:8083/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

And here is the error I get when I try to a `mvn clean install`

```
Failure to find mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.0.5 in
http://xxxx:8083/nexus/content/groups/public
```

How can I force nexus to download the artifact from my public repositories to nexus? Do I have to add it manually?

Comment: Could you provide your maven settings.xml?
I have chacked the dependency with empty pom.xml and default settings.xml. It works fine.
Looks like You have a issue with repositories configuration.

Comment: I added the other information in my settings.xml to the question. I checked the central repository and it seems to be there

Comment: I supposed your pom.xml is pointing to your internal nexus repository. You can add proxy repository to your internal repository. Refer to http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html . After add proxy repository, remember add tour internal nexus repository group. You also can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860370/nexus-proxy-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell maven to use your maven repository. To do this, modify $HOME/.m2/settings.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://xxxx:8083/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies></proxies>
  <servers></servers>
  <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

The nexus profile is configured to download from the central repository with `a bogus URL` of `http://central`.

This URL is overridden by the mirror setting in the same `settings.xml` file to point to the URL of your `single Nexus group`. The nexus group is then listed as an active profile in the activeProfiles element.

Suppose you have repository Central that has repository path `http://xxxx:8083/nexus/content/repositories/central` and also point Remote Storage Location to `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` you can change `http://central` to `http://xxxx:8083/nexus/content/repositories/central` or `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`.

in your pom.xml, use below dependency to getting mysql-connector.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.33</version>
</dependency>
```

See also: [Getting started with Nexus maven repository manager](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html)

Hope this help.

Comment: mmm changed my settings.xml accordingly but I still get the same error. Do I have to configure http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ in the nexus console before this can work?

Comment: @Ayrad yes,  but as far as I know nexus add it by default. If it did not appear in your public repository, you should add it by yourself by make it as proxy repository and also add it into public repo group.

Comment: in my nexus console all the configured repositories are local (all paths point to local server:8083/nexus/content ...) including the central repository which has a status of "In Service - Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable"

Comment: @Ayrad make sure you have central repo that Remote storage location point to http:// repo1.maven.org/maven2 and also add into your public repository group.
Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable mab be this link can help you https://support.sonatype.com/entries/41253986-A-proxy-repository-is-not-working-status-says-Remote-Automatically-Blocked-and-Unavailable-

Comment: @Ayrad I post how to Maven Central Repository as proxy in Nexus manager at my blog http://wittakarn.blogspot.com/2014/10/maven-central-repository-as-proxy-in.html.

Comment: thanks for the great blog post. I notice now that the remote storage location already points to repo1.maven.org but that url is not accessible from the server. This might be the issue. Will try to fix it and report back!

Comment: `mvn help:effective-pom` is always a good point to check what's really used.

Comment: after unblocking http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/  from the server hosting nexus I am now able to correctly download the artifact and it works. Only thing still vague is: Is  putting the external url in settings.xml under <plugins reposity> necessary or only configuring it in the nexus console for remote reposity enough.. but it works now !

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that you have included two different versions for mysql-connector-java?
I used to have an error like that, it turned out I had accidentally included another version, so this specific version was not accessed (it was a transitive dependency, which for peculiar reasons I could not exclude). I moved the dependency in the beginning of all other dependencies (in your case it might be in the end),and it worked. Theoretically having two versions of same dependency should not throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the available versions of MySQL connector
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java , click on any version, it will give your the dependency.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. Does it mean I have to manually download the jar and add it to nexus? I thought the point of the repositories was to automatically download these dependencies